# jQuery disable enable event handler of link

Tags: jquery

here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/4WyPq/

So basically when I click 'button1' it animates then disables the button, after that I need to press button2 and enable the 'button1' event so I press again 'button1' it should do the same event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind a click event to a link, you HAVE to include the click handler function.

```
$(this).bind('click');
```

does not do anything because there is no handler function.  You would have to pass the click handler function again if you want to rebind it.  You could do that by breaking the click handler out into it's own local function and then using that function each time you bind the click event.  You could do that like this:

```
function bindA1(force) {
    var a1 = $('.a1');
    if (force || a1.hasClass("disabled")) {
        a1.click(function() {
            $(this)
                .addClass("disabled")
                .unbind("click")
                .animate({"top": "+=50px"}, "slow");
            return(false);
        }).removeClass("disabled");
    }
}

bindA1(true);

$('.a2').click(function () {
    bindA1();
    return(false);
});
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3kjaR/

If you really intend to enable and disable the handlers for links like this, it may be easier to just set a property that you check rather than actually remove the event handlers.

You could use a flag like this:

```
$('.a1').click(function (){
    if (!$(this).data("disabled")) {
        $('.a1').animate({"top": "+=50px"}, "slow");
        $(this).data("disabled", true);
    }
});

$('.a2').click(function (){
    $(".a1").data("disabled", false);
});
​
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/NSZ8P/

Comment: i think this one is easy to use. I choose u jfriend00

Answer (score 2):

- use `.off()` to remove the handler
- use `.on()` to bind it again
- use a reusable function for binding

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4WyPq/1/):

```
$(function() {

    function clickHandler() {
        $(this).animate({
            "top": "+=50px"
        }, "slow").off('click');
        return false;
    }

    $('.a1').on('click', clickHandler);

    $('.a2').on('click',function() {
        $('.a1').on('click', clickHandler);
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: One has to be careful with this one because successive clicks on `a2` will give you duplicate click handlers on `a1`.

Answer (score 0):

I played with your fiddle, and gave you a different option, instead of messing with the memory locations for the bind event and having to get all confused... try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4WyPq/2/

```
$('.a1').click(function (){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("disabled")){
        $(this).addClass("disabled");
        $('.a1').animate({"top": "+=50px"}, "slow");
    }
});

$('.a2').click(function (){
    $(".a1").removeClass("disabled");
});
```

Comment: You can also use .data() of the element, but I avoid this because IE is kinda picky with that stuff. However jfriend00 has a good example in another answer.