# Disable and enable click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have this code:

```
jQuery(".view-kems-tickets-calendar td.single-day").not(".no-entry, .empty").click(function() {
  jQuery(".all-day-items", this).slideDown("slow");
  jQuery(this).off("click");
});

jQuery(".view-kems-tickets-calendar .close-all-day").click(function() {
  jQuery(".all-day-items").slideUp("fast", function() {
  });
});
```

So what it does: It makes clickable td.single-day and displays the .all-day-items class element which **exists inside of this td tag**. The .all-day-items element contains .close-all-day element which closes previously opened .all-day-items element. The problem is that while clicking at .close-all-day element at the same time I click in td.single-day so it closes and opens again. I put this line:

```
jQuery(this).off("click");
```

to disable it, but how do I activate it again in complete function? I tried couple of methods, but it always behave as before (it closes and opens again the .close-all-day element).

This is how it doesn't work: :) the code: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgJZOp

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9898789/1025201) answer, if that helps you

Comment: I think you are rather looking for jQuery stopPropagation() method - http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps you:

```
jQuery(".view-kems-tickets-calendar td.single-day").not(".no-entry, .empty").click(function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is('.close-all-day')){
        jQuery(".all-day-items", this).slideDown("slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: could you please add the html code aswell? this would make it easier to help you :)